# Community Sharing Sets: Grand Child of the Account

Tags: community, napili, sharing-sets

I do have a Custom object: Information__c which is a child object of the Case. As we all know, Case is a Child object to the Account. Now I wanted to restrict(visible to) Informations to specific to each account.

So on the Community Sharing sets, I have had:
For the Object: Information>> `User:Account = Information:CaseLookUp__c.Account` to **Read Only**. With this, any different Account user still see other Account's Information records.

My question: Can't we use sharing sets to TWO level lookups? If not, do I need to explicitly create a Lookup to Account on the Information object?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. The best thing to do is try to do it with two levels. If you can't, then create your lookup directly to the account and try that. Then create 2 rules. 1 for the case and 1 for information objects. Sometimes, trying something is the best way to see if it works :)